# How to Implement a press event in a custom React Native Component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I created a native UI component for android using react native, I can display it on the screen but I'd like to add an onPress event to it. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your components with TouchableOpacity or TouchableHighlight. And you can easily add event listener in this way:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={MY_FUNC}> 
  <MyComponent />
</TouchableOpacity>
```